# How does one deploy a React / Apollo GraphQl app to Heroku?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, graphql, react-apollo

I have a (relatively) finished app [here](https://github.com/JoshuaPhillips/topdeckr). At this stage I'm just looking to deploy.

I've chosen Heroku at this point, as it seems the simplest option, and it's free. However, I can't seem to figure out how to actually deploy, either using the CLI or GitHub integration.

I *was* getting errors about the buildpack, which I managed to solve by changing the folder with the Git Repo in it (from one folder to two subfolders). However, I can't work out how to link the deployments together (client / server), so there's nothing actually on the page.

**Folder Setup**

```
App
    client
        ...
        [Apollo Client / React]
        package.json <- used for the buildpack in Heroku
        ...
    server
        ...
        [Apollo Server / Mongoose / MongoDb Server]
        package.json <- same thing
        ...
```

I've tried using the [Apollo Docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/deployment/heroku/) but they're not really helping unfortunately. I've tried looking here for further answers and a general web search, but to be honest I'm not really sure what the *issue* is, let alone how to fix it.

I'm happy to try other options, but free is quite important so I'm not sure that I have many other choices.

All help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You are just getting a blank page?  Have you built and ran the server on Heroku, it may be as simple as the server not running on the back-end.  I'll show you my setup, it took seemingly 50 commits to Heroku to finally get the right combination working, Heroku just isn't setup well for running a client and server together, and it can be confusing since the build process has changed a lot.

First in package.json, be sure you have a heroku-postbuild script to install and run the client.  Under scripts you need `"heroku-postbuild": "cd client/ && npm install && npm run build"`  This script might need adjusted depending whether on Mac Linux or PC, I use Windows.

In my server index file, I have the path for Apollo server pointed at `server.applyMiddleware({ app, path: "/graphql" });`

I use express to get my React client...

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
  app.get("/*", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../client/build/index.html"));
  });
} else {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/client/public")));
  app.get("/*", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./client/public/index.html"));
  });
}
```

I made a Procfile in the root folder with the only command inside `web: npm run server` Heroku listens for this file to run commands in npm automatically.

In my Apollo client index files, I have the httpLink uri pointed at `/graphql`.  My websocket link (which may not matter for your project) points directly to Heroku `wss://yourappname.herokuapp.com/graphql`.

Perhaps that'll be enough to get you closer to a solution.